# Round Robin Assignment implementation (database)

Tags: database, scheduling, round-robin

I'm currently in the process of implementing a number of different assignment algorithms for a `SalesLead` <--> `SalesPerson` situation. The general idea is quite simple:

1. A `SalesLead` signs up on a public website
2. The code automatically assigns the `SalesLead` to a `SalesPerson` using round-robin scheduling (Leads are assigned to `SalesPersons` in the same order)

I'm having some serious coders-block in how to actually perform this outside of making sure I pull the agents from the database in the same order each time, and using another table to store the last agent that was assigned a SalesLead (which may actually be useful for building a report, or at least having a trace-back method later on). Am I way off base?

**Clarification:**  The code doesn't currently match a sales person to a lead. This is a completely new function. Currently they can sign up for a specific SalesPerson, but we'd like them to be able to be assigned automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty simple really: when a SalesPerson is created, give them a LastActivityDate.  When they are assigned a SalesLead, update that date to the current date.  Give a SalesLead, as it comes in, to a SalesPerson with the least recent activity date.

Can be done easily in SQL or code.

Comment: I like this, it's simple, but effective. I'd never considered adding a timestamp column.

Comment: You just have to cover a few corner cases.  Like if a SalesPerson goes on leave, set their activity date to NULL (so its not picked up) and when they get back, set it to now so they go back in the rotation.  This system is then quite fair.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table that matches SalesLeads and SalesPersons together and you timestamp it, you don't need a separate table to keep track of the last SalesPerson picked.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you'd actually want it to be a datetime, not a timestamp field, but @David's idea is the same.  Keep track of the last sales lead assigned to a sales person and record the time at which it was assigned.  You can then pick the next sales person to assign a lead to by finding the sales person who does not have one assigned or the sales person whose last assigned lead is the oldest.

Answer (score 1):

Check out how Salesforce does it:
http://forums.sforce.com/sforce/board/message?board.id=custom_formula&message.id=533

MOD an ID by the number of salespeople + 1 and then assign 1 to Joe, 2, to Tom, etc.